# GitHub API - Get commit details via access token

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v3

With the GitHub API, let's say I have used OAuth and I have the client secret of a user. Let's say I also have a repo, say `myname/project`, as well as a commit ID, say `asdfghjkl123`. With this information, I know I can [get the details of the commit](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/commits/#get-a-single-commit), but how can I do this on "behalf" of the user? Basically, I want to use the access token I have so that the rate limit is based on the user. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in [this issue](https://github.com/all-contributors/all-contributors-cli/issues/121#issue-393718379)

> A way to provide a `GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN` env var which is attached to GitHub requests to avoid api limits, as in [this PR](https://github.com/all-contributors/all-contributors-cli/pull/122/files)

I always set `GITHUB_AUTH_TOKEN` to my token before making my curl GitHub API calls: I then benefit from an higher rate limit.